# Django Mysql Migration Error 150 with FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, django, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I need help debugging a migration.

I tried to execute each query step by step to found where django migration stops.

This query fails:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `elezioniAgendaCore_comments` ADD CONSTRAINT `elezioniAgendaCore_comments_uid_id_670175fa07fa7b47_fk_user_uid` FOREIGN KEY (`uid_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`uid`);
```

With Error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'activedoc.#sql-3f7_2b' (errno: 150)
```

I have tow tables.

TABLE user:

```
mysql> show columns from user;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid               | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name              | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| surname           | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| email             | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

TABLE elezioniAgendaComments:

```
mysql> show columns from elezioniAgendaCore_comments;
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| signature        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| message          | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created          | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| published        | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| adempimento_id   | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| parentComment_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| uid_id           | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I found one table was created with MyISAM engine:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE user;
```

[...]

```
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=307 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

The other table:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE elezioniAgendaCore_comments;
```

[...]

```
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Then I migrated to InnoDB both tables. No errors this time.